# Is there any way to jump to specific tab of Tabman IOS library directly?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using [Tabman](https://github.com/uias/Tabman) library to achieve Pager Sliding tab views in my IOS Swift Application. I am having the following issue.

#### Issue Description

I have a list of 300 items to show in tabs. It is very inefficient to load all the tabs at once as it requires a user to wait and also consumes a lot of memory. Therefore, I have achieved a dynamic behavior and only loading 3 tabs at once, and similarly, while user swipes, I load 3 more and so on.

**Is it possible to jump to a specific tab and have the same behavior?** E.g., From the home screen user has given an input item number 100. Now when I go to the viewController/Storyboard of Tabman, I don't know how to have the same behavior as the item 100th should be active tab and 99th and 101st should be on left and right respectively.

Please help! Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this amazing library called [Parchment](https://github.com/rechsteiner/Parchment). It's perfect for what I want to achieve.